# Adding a Listener to the LayersControl in a leaflet addon map in Vaadin (Java)

Tags: java, leaflet, listener, vaadin8

I am using a leaflet map (vaadin addon in Java). I would like to add a listener the the control panel of the map.
The method provided by leaflet is:

```
addListener(Class<?> eventType, Object target, Method method)
```

The control panel contains several checkboxes, one checkbox for each map layer. I would like to find out which layers checkbox was clicked.

[image: map with control panel]

"Method" is from reflection and I am new to reflection. I don't know how to write this Listener. Maybe someone could help. I tried:

```
Method m = Class.forName(LMTBLayer.class.getName()).getDeclaredMethod("receiveClick");
field.getMap().getLayersControl().addListener(MouseEvents.ClickEvent.class,layers.getMtbLayer(), m);
```

"LMTBLayer" is a map layer. "field.getMap().getLayersControl()" returns the control panel. "layers.getMtbLayer()" returns the actual layer object. But the method "receiveClick" is never invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A college pointed me into the right direction. The listeners have to be added to the vaadin leaflet map.

```
map.addBaseLayerChangeListener( );
map.addOverlayAddListener( );
map.addOverlayRemoveListener( );
```